# Box in fluidPage, basic shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to use box() element in classic shiny app? As classic app I mean not shiny dashboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's possible - you can use [useShinydashboard](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.4.4/topics/useShinydashboard)() from library([shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets))

Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinydashboard(),

   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      mainPanel(
         box(plotOutput("distPlot"), title = "My box title", footer = "My box footer", collapsible = TRUE, status = "success")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```